# I need some help to identify a few parts

Tags: diodes, zener

I need some help to identify parts D2 and ZD3 in the photo below.

I can't find anything for replacement using their markings which I believe are B704 and XF81, but I could be wrong.

[image]

Comment: Remove them from board and measure the forward voltage.. Another set like zener.. You can try measuring that too by connecting with a series load.

Comment: Why do you think they are in need of replacement?

Comment: the word you want is `identify` , not "indicate"

Comment: What makes you think it is XF81 and not XE51?

Comment: I agree with Andrew. That looks like XE51.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify+parts+smd+code

Comment: I zoomed in with GIMP and tried contrast and brightness settings, but they are no more clear than they are now. That could be XB51.

Comment: Looks more like XP51 or XR51

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps guess game, but since marking is ZD3, and I see numbers 704, that could most likely be 1N704 Zener diode (but who knows :) )

The other one (if colleagues are right and it is indeed 51) could be something similar with RGF1J/51A which could be found on mouser, but that's really weak shoot :)

The best way to determine what are those components would be to put them on semiconductor curve tracer. That would for sure resolve whole mystery.